# context.xml not getting copied from META-INF folder to Tomcat conf

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, server.xml, context.xml, contextroot

I am building a maven war and I intend to keep context root same irrespective of what war file name(across snapshots/releases). In that quest I did the following.

1. I created a file (matching with desired context root name) helloApp.xml in conf\Catalina\localhost

> < Context 
>   docBase="C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.18\trial\helloApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" />

2. I place the WAR file in the above folder

and I am able to access the appplication with context root -/helloApp

As my snapshot keeps changing I intend to have above context.xml(helloApp.xml) contents in my war. so

1. I created a context.xml in src/main/resources/META-INF  with content

> < Context 
>   docBase="C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.18\trial\helloApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war"  />

2. I added copyXML="true" to server.xml

> < Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
>                        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" copyXML="true">

But the content of context.xml is not getting copied to the existing helloApp.xml  in conf\Catalina\localhost .

Is there a better way to configure docBase so that I can modify it as my war name changes?

P.S. I do not wish to use finalName in the war as I want the build to reflect the release. Also I understand I could use maven tomcat plugin.

Comment: Note that you can name your war to reflect the release in a way that tomcat recognizes as the version. This is done to support parallel deployments. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment

Comment: Brett- That is good information.Thanks. I can rename the file as helloApp##1.0-SNAPSHOT.war and get the desired path - /helloApp irrespective of the what is after ##.  This is a good aproach if I wish to rename my file for Tomcat. I do not wish to rename the file. I modified my question a bit. Please take a look. –  pingu 1 hour ago